# I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed (shows that splash when I open Management Studio) but DB engine is 2005 express?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am trying to restore a backup of a SQL Server 2008 database - but my engine is SQL Server 2005 Express. When I try and choose a different in the Management studio login, there is nothing BUT my SQL Server Express.

Now I am getting the *`RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally`* on a 4+ GB DB that I need to restore.

Has anyone seen this? I am sure I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 (that's why I see it when I open the Management studio) ...so why do I only have SQL Server 2005 Express engine?

Thanks!
todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you only have the SQL Server 2008 R2 client tools installed.  You will see the SQL Server 2008 R2 information on SSMS, but that doesn't indicate whether any server is installed.

I assume that SQL Server 2005 Express was installed already.

Of course, as you're seeing, the restore of a SQL Server 2008 backup will fail on the 2005 Express server.

You will probably have to install SQL Server 2008 R2 server again to get it installed.  There are certain minimum requirements to install the server.  I'm not positive, but I think if your computer doesn't meet the requirements, the install will automatically install client tools only.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I have a very well equipped laptop, so I wonder why it would have only have installed the tools?  Ill try and reinstall.

Comment: Some Microsoft software selects a 'tools-only' install when you install on a workstation-class product instead of a server product. Or, you might have the R2 database engine installed but not registered in the client tools.